# Why can't I access the value of the field in jsp (it returns null)?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

I've the following javascript function:

```
function confirmaEnviar()
    {        


          document.getElementById("data").value =clave2.value;

        alert(document.getElementById("data").value);
   more code here
```

Where I check I'm able to asign a new value tu data;

data being defined like this:

```
 <form action="client.json" method="post" name="usuario" id="usuario">

 more code here

 <input  type="hidden" name="data" id="data" value="prueba" />

 more code here

 </form>
```

Later on the jsp part:

```
      <div><a href="javascript:void();" onclick="       
   javascript:if(confirmaEnviar())$('#usuario').submit();

 <%
<%
 more code here

 String str= request.getParameter("data");
```

str is always null, can you point me out about what I could do?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you submitted the form? Or are you expecting that `String str= request.getParameter("data");` will, on the server side and after the request has been handled, return the `<input>` on the client side...?

Answer (score 4):

I think you have change the attribute action="client.json"  to action="client.jsp" .

May be the page can't get the request parameters.. I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

The str variable will have the value of the "data" parameter in the request that caused the page to be painted.  It seems likely that the first time the page is painted, there is no "data" parameter in the request; there is a "data" field in the form that will be submitted in the future, but we are still in the present.

The only time that the "data" request parameter will have a value is when a form was submitted before the page was painted.

Also (this is not related to your question), it is a bad practice to include Java code on your JSP pages; use java in servlets or controllers (if you use Spring) and use jsp pages for view.